# VMWare: Access VM folder from Host

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-player

I have my hots and guest machine both on Windows 7. I know I can access folders of host machine from guest using shared folders option.

But I would like to know is it possible in opposite? I have shared some folders on my guest OS in VM and would like to access those from host machine.

please advice me on this. I am using VMWare Player 4.0

Thanks

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=share%20folders%20windows

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Thx for the link , but my question is involves VM Ware. So I need answer in that context.

Comment: There is no answer in that context. VMWare does not have the feature.